# Regular Expression pattern issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to delete all the characters other than letter and number from a given string. I used the pattern below but it still returns string without any change.

```
Regex rex = new Regex("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/");

Response.Write(rex.Replace("asd123!-<>@;',.", ""));
```

It suppose to return `"asd123"`

Regex patterns are like alien language to me and I dont know how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, you don't need to delimit regex patterns with `/` characters.

Try this:

```
Regex rex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
Response.Write(rex.Replace("asd123!-<>@;',.", ""));
```

Comment: Wouldnt this replace the `asd123` leaving only the characters he doesnt want?

Comment: @paqogomez No. The character class is negated, so it will replace anything that's *not* in that class.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
string str = "a@4( asd1";
Regex rex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");           
System.Console.WriteLine(rex.Replace(str, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

With C# you don't need the slashes (`/`) aroud your regular expression:

```
Regex rex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");

Response.Write(rex.Replace("asd123!-<>@;',.", ""));
```